# Local notification(s) does not repeat on each day for every hour using UserNotifications framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, unusernotificationcenter, usernotifications

We did not get the local notification on next day for every hour using UNNotificationCenterCalendarTrigger.

What we have currently, the current day receiving local notification(s) on repeated hour interval, but from next day on-words does not receive notification using UserNotifications framework, but with deprecated UILocalNotification framework notification delivered with the help of fire date, repeat calendar, and repeat interval property.

We referred to apple documentation, the older notification framework which had a fire date and repeat interval. The date components are more flexible but there is no easy way to fully replicate the fireDate property of the older framework.

What we required, to remind the task daily in the application, have the notification(s) repeat daily at the same time using hour, minutes, and seconds components with UNNotificationCenterCalendarTrigger, and once the task is done by the user the repeat notification for the current day should be stopped and notification(s) on next day must be repeated as expected on an hourly interval.

So is there any exact replacement for fire date, repeat calendar, and repeat interval property of UILocalNotification framework with UserNotifications framework?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BjornB. We referred to apple documentation, the older notification framework which had a fire date and repeat interval. The date components are more flexible but there is no easy way to fully replicate the fireDate property of the older framework.

Comment: What we required, to remind the task daily in the application, have the notification(s) repeat daily at the same time using hour, minutes, and seconds components with UNNotificationCenterCalendarTrigger, and once the task is done by the user the repeat notification for the current day should be stopped and notification(s) on next day must be repeated as expected on an hourly interval.